# Best way to track Torah learning

Tags: torah-study, tanach, siyum, shas

What is a good method to track your progress in learning all of the Torah. (Tanach, Shas, etc.)

I was thinking of an excel template if anyone has one or for other suggestions.

Comment: If you can't remember if you learned something without a tracker you probably have to review it anyway

Comment: I have a simple note in my note app where I track when I learned what text, with whom and at what dates. At the level of a masechta, sefer of tshuvot, portions of SA, etc. Not individual dapim.

Comment: @DoubleAA There are several reasons to do it anyways. One of which is that although we all learned it in the womb it's helpful to know "I once learned this" or "this is brand new stuff".

Comment: I believe the best would be an excel template for my purposes and I am just wondering how to get one.

Answer (score 2):

check out...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.first.torahtracker

> Keep track of your Torah learning with the Torah Tracker app!! Whether you are following a daily cycle, weekly cycle, or learning at your own pace, mark down all your accomplishments and view your progress!
> • Now you won’t forget what Daf or Mishna you were up to, you can just check your Torah Tracker!
> • Push yourself to learn more by viewing how much you’ve learned and how much you still have to learn! If you finish once, that doesn’t mean you’re done! Reset and keep learning! Chazarah!!

*on a personal note especially like how the percentages are shown for each category and subcategory and find this app motivating to see the progression of each milestone.

Answer (score 0):

Go here to create calendars for Shas, Mishnayos and Mishna Berura - https://www.shaschabura.org/create-calendar/